# I have no idea how to use as3corelib

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to develop an application to a web page I get the JSON but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Depending on your needs you might not need as3corelib. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have downvoted your question, it just has no details on your needs and what you have to start with. Edit your question and add details.

Comment: This is not a question...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any lib to use JSON, it's natively supported since FP 11.
Just use your received JSON object as dynamic objecsts.

If you need to use earlier version of FP, you can use [this](http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/) lib instead